# Cannot access beyond the root directory in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am hosting my ASP.Net application in IIS. But I am not able to navigate beyond the root folder.

I have created a website  in IIS with the following physical path as this is where my web.config is availble: `D:\SourceCodes\App_Source_Code\src\MyWebSite`

The Application is loading fine, but the images and CSS were not loading. On investigation, I found out that as my images are available at the following location, the images were not loaded    `D:\SourceCodes\App_Source_Code\src\MyWebSite\CDN\2015.1.1.6\images\home`

I then turned on Directory Browsing and found out that I was able to navigate to only upto `\MyWebSite\CDN\`folder and the folders under `CDN` it were not listed.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here to do anything other than guess at possible causes.  The first one that comes to mind is that there is some sort of permissions issue.  Not that you want to leave the app in this state, but have you tried giving "Everyone" access to CDN and below?

Comment: check to see whether the folder is hidden.

Comment: did you ever resolve this ?